# PHP How To Restrict domain to send POST request

Tags: php, code-access-security

I need to restrict POST request from specific domain. As far I know, HTTP_REFERER checking cannot be a good solution because it can be spoofed. So what can be the good solution when two different websites from different technology and web servers will work together?

Comment: You mean that you want only one other server to be allowed to send POST requests to your server? You can use a shared mutating code system.

Comment: There are a number of solutions from limiting the accepted IP address to signing the payload using a shared secret.

Comment: I want to allow some specific domain to send post request. Actually I cannot understand how to generate some random keys and check those into different servers.

Comment: reverse DNS lookup on `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`, but your system will slow to a crawl.

Comment: should be more clearly specified ... examples and etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heres a method you could try, by adding a hidden field within your form that is session values that are set server side. This way if the form has not originated from your server the session would not have been set and the values would not match.

Example:

```
<?php 
session_start();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    if(isset($_SESSION['security']) && 
       isset($_SESSION['security_key']) && 
       !empty($_POST[$_SESSION['security_key']]) && 
       $_POST[$_SESSION['security_key']] == $_SESSION['security'])
    {
        /* forms post is from domain as session would 
           not have been started and security would not have been set */
        echo 'good';
    }else{
        /* forms post is not from domain */
        echo 'bad';
    }
    $_SESSION['security_key'] = sha1(microtime(true)+1);
    $_SESSION['security'] = sha1(microtime(true));
}else{
    $_SESSION['security_key'] = sha1(microtime(true)+1);
    $_SESSION['security'] = sha1(microtime(true));
}
?>

<form method="POST" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="<?=$_SESSION['security_key'];?>" value="<?=$_SESSION['security'];?>"/>
  <p><input type="text" name="Text" size="20"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

Alternatively you could use encryption instead of hashing, that way you could check the values:

```
<?php 
session_start();
define('SECURE_KEY',$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    if(isset($_SESSION['security_key']) && isset($_SESSION['security'])){
        //Decrypt
        list($servername,$userip) = explode('X',decrypt(base64_decode($_SESSION['security'])));

        //Check the decrypted values
        if($servername == $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] && $userip == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']){
            /* forms post is from domain as session would
            not have been started and security would not have been set */
            echo 'good';
        }else{
            echo 'bad';
        }

    }else{
        /* forms post is not from domain */
        echo 'bad';
    }

    $_SESSION['security_key'] = sha1(microtime(true));
    $_SESSION['security'] = base64_encode(encrypt($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'X'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
}else{
    $_SESSION['security_key'] = sha1(microtime(true));
    $_SESSION['security'] = base64_encode(encrypt($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'X'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
}

function encrypt($string, $key = 'PrivateKey', $secret = 'SecretKey', $method = 'AES-256-CBC') {
    // hash
    $key = hash('sha256', $key);
    // create iv - encrypt method AES-256-CBC expects 16 bytes
    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret), 0, 16);
    // encrypt
    $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $method, $key, 0, $iv);
    // encode
    return base64_encode($output);
}

function decrypt($string, $key = 'PrivateKey', $secret = 'SecretKey', $method = 'AES-256-CBC') {
    // hash
    $key = hash('sha256', $key);
    // create iv - encrypt method AES-256-CBC expects 16 bytes
    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret), 0, 16);
    // decode
    $string = base64_decode($string);
    // decrypt
    return openssl_decrypt($string, $method, $key, 0, $iv);
}
?>

<form method="POST" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="<?=$_SESSION['security_key'];?>" value="<?=$_SESSION['security'];?>"/>
  <p><input type="text" name="Text" size="20"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: would it work if the form is submitted from remote server? I mean would session value be same?

Comment: Remote server? The steps would be, user hits your site and the values are generated, form is rendered with its hidden field, user posts form and all is good. If form is from another domain values would not have been created and would fail validation.

Comment: Yes, remote domain, and so I'm tensed about security